# JITSI video meet - Is there any config or API to kick out all the participants when the host/moderator leaves the meeting?

Tags: jitsi, jitsi-meet

I installed JITSI and created a video meeting platform. I created a meeting and shared it with my friends.
I am the host/moderator of the meeting. My friends who joined the meeting are all participants. Now when I leave/disconnect the meeting, it is not disconnecting for the participants a**nd they are still accessing the meeting room without me(host (or) moderator).**

Now, I am searching for a **solution to remove the participants when the moderator leaves the meeting.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you solve this ?

Comment: @ShankarSBavan No. The moderator cant kick out participants after leaving the meeting. The first participant who joins the meeting will become the moderator once the actual moderator leaves the meeting

Comment: I found different solution for this. when host end the meeting (readyToClose), redirected the page to another using pusher

Comment: @ShankarSBavan great. can you answer the solution with some details in the answer section?

Comment: are using any framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used Laravel php framework.
you can assign particular user as moderator. you can use readyToClose api method to pass the redirection url.

in my example, Im passing the meeting end url through the controller. when host end the meeting I used socket to send the signal to all other participants.

```
    <script>
        var domain = "meet.example.com";
        if(isModerator == true) {
           var options = {
                userInfo: {
                    moderator: true,
                },
                roomName: "123",
                width: "100%",
                height: "100%",
                parentNode: document.querySelector('#container'),
            }
        } else {
           var options = {
                userInfo: {
                    moderator: false,
                },
                roomName: "123",
                width: "100%",
                height: "100%",
                parentNode: document.querySelector('#container'),
            }
        }
           var api = new JitsiMeetExternalAPI(domain, options);
           api.on('readyToClose', () => {
             window.location.href = '{{ $meeting_end_url }}';
           });
    </script>

     //pusher
     channel.bind('meeting ended', function (meeting) {
           window.setTimeout(function() {
           window.location.href = '/'; <-- redirect path
        }, 5000);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The moderator can't kick out participants after leaving the meeting. The first participant who joins the meeting will become the moderator once the actual moderator leaves the meeting.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in button onclick()

```
endMeetingForAll () {
    const { _allParticipant,_changeNotification} = this.props;
    _allParticipant.map((participant) => {
        if( !participant.local) {
            APP.store.dispatch(kickParticipant(participant.id));
        }
    });
    window.APP.conference.hangup(false);
    executeCommand('hangup');
    window.close();
}
```

Use the all participant from mapstateToProps return like this:

```
_allParticipant: getParticipants(state)
```

Answer (score 0):

Jitsi now includes a feature allowing a moderator to end a conference for all participants: https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/pull/10838.